# magento custom url for shopping cart

Tags: magento, routes, router

Is there any way i can have a custom URL for the shopping cart of magento ?
ex: when you add a product to the cart, you get the link as 
you will go to http://www.domain.com/magento/checkout/cart/

I want to change this to 
http://www.domain.com/magento/checkout/CUSTOM_NAME_GOES_HERE/

i tried to edit

```
class Mage_Checkout_Helper_Url extends Mage_Core_Helper_Url
public function getCartUrl()
{
return $this->_getUrl('checkout/cart');
}
```

but it dosent works

Answer (score 0):

easy as pie: go to catalog > URL rewrite management and add your rewrite condition and rewrite this whatever you like. and change the checkout/cart to indicate new route

Comment: i went to catalog > URL rewrite management and used "custom" from the drop down..what should i be writing in object id type and where exactly should i change the checkout/cart to indicate new route

Comment: there are only 5 fields or so there and experimenting with meaningful combinations would take you 10 minutes to test all them out